# Using Socrata API distance_in_meters() function with separate latitude, longitude field

Tags: soql, socrata

I am trying to retrieve information about trees surrounding a given location from the Socrata API.

[API Endpoint Description](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/2015-Street-Tree-Census-Tree-Data/uvpi-gqnh)

I found two functions `within_circle(...)` and `distance_in_meters(...)` which I could use to filter the data set. The problem is, that those functions need either a location or a point data type which is not present in the data set.
There is, however a latitude and longitude field.
Is there any method to utilize those functions or get nearby trees other way?

Tried this, but `POINT(0 0)` must be the point of the tree.

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?$where=within_circle( 'POINT(0 0)' ,0,0,400)
```

I need something like this.

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?$where=within_circle( make_point(latitude, longitude) ,0,0,400)
```

[SoQL](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: Could you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already done so, you may want to submit this question at https://support.socrata.com. In addition to the possibility that the people there will have an answer I do not, it would serve as some feedback that a function like what you had in mind would be useful.

I cannot think of a way to do exactly what you have in mind. Really, what I mean is a way that is within your power (or mine). The owner of the dataset could create a Point column -- and you may want to reach out to the NYC open data team to ask for that if you have not already done so.

However, since the X and Y coordinates, in feet, are present, you should be able to use the Pythagorean theorem to determine the distance from any given point. For that matter, the size of a degree of latitude or longitude cannot vary that much over an area as small as NYC so you could do the same thing with those values and save having to figure out the X and Y of your reference point.

Good luck!

Jon